# "Nested clasp projects are not supported" error fix

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I have been trying to use clasp with appscript ,to develop apps locally on my computer.

I used the following commands in the correct order.

1.npm install @google/clasp -g

2.clasp login

3.clasp create --title "test".

After the execution of this command, the following error occurs.

"Nested clasp projects are not supported"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check the parent directories, there's likely a loose `clasp.json` file there causing this error.

Comment: I cannot find the clasp json file anywhere. I created the folder in Documents of my computer

Comment: Did you also check hidden files; `.clasp.json` ?

Comment: I also checked the hidden files using ls-a command in terminal. it doesn't show .clasp.json file

Comment: What dir are you in? Is this your first ever install of clasp?